Error de datos o conexion usando https://secure.epayco.co/validation/v1/reference/ + ref_payco
Estoy tratando de realizar una validacion de transacción en pagina de respuesta despues de un pago por Epayco en su versión standar checkout, donde al terminar el pago lo redirecciona al sitio del comercio a una pagina de confirmación. Se realiza una consulta a los datos de la transacción a traves de un peticion get a Epayco pero siempre arroja un error de conexión.
¿Alguna explicación sobre lo que está sucediendo o sugerir una solución para resolverlo?
Dentro del controlador se realiza una petición get a esta url: https://secure.epayco.co/validation/v1/reference/ + ref_payco
Esto para obtener los datos asociados a la transacción pero siempre se obtiene este resultado. No se encuentra información en la documentación sobre parámetros de conexión adicionales ni temas similares, y tampoco hay documentación para este método en la referencia de la API.
{
"status": false,
"message": "Error de datos o conexión.",
"data": {
"status": "error",
"description": "Error de datos o conexión verifique de nuevo."
}
}
Lo que esperaba era los datos de la transacción, por ejemplo:
{
x_cust_id_cliente:1379695,
x_ref_payco:206381484,
x_id_factura:"11015",
x_id_invoice:"11015",
x_description:"Camiseta Sport",
x_amount:85900,
x_amount_country:85900,
x_amount_ok:85900,
x_tax:0,
x_amount_base:85900,
x_currency_code:"COP",
x_bank_name:"NA",
x_cardnumber:"*******",
x_quotas:0,
x_respuesta:"Cancelada",
x_response:"Cancelada",
x_approval_code:"000000",
x_transaction_id:"48771920271208",
x_fecha_transaccion:"2024-04-23 11:28:44",
x_transaction_date:"2024-04-23 11:28:44",
x_cod_respuesta:2,
x_cod_response:2,
x_response_reason_text:"02-Transacción Cancelada por el cliente",
x_errorcode:"02",
x_cod_transaction_state:11,
x_transaction_state:"Cancelada",
x_franchise:"N/A",
x_business:"Paola Andrea Riascos",
x_customer_doctype:"N/A",
x_customer_document:"N/A",
x_customer_name:"NA",
x_customer_lastname:"NA",
x_customer_email:"htest@gmail.com",
x_customer_phone:"0000000",
x_customer_movil:"N/A",
x_customer_ind_pais:null,
x_customer_country:"CO",
x_customer_city:null,
x_customer_address:"NA",
x_test_request:"TRUE",
x_extra1:null,
x_extra2:null,
x_extra3:null,
x_extra4:null,
x_extra5:null,
x_extra6:null,
x_extra7:null,
x_extra8:null,
x_extra9:null,
x_extra10:null,
x_tax_ico:0,
x_payment_date:null,
x_signature:"d8dea1934fd02bfeea4d4a71cab0adc36e4b1f1d46f5e2e7682395eb93fe5c8e",
x_transaction_cycle:null,
is_processable:true,
}

Ya encontré la solución al problema, por si a alguien le sirve.
La solución fue actualizar el plugin WooCommerce Epayco Gateway a la versión 8.0.2, que es la más reciente. El sitio web estaba utilizando la versión 6.0.0 del plugin cuando ocurrió el error.
Al revisar el código fuente y los comentarios de los commits del plugin en github.
https://github.com/epayco/Plugin_ePayco_WooCommerce/releases/tag/v8.0.2
Se notó una actualización en el proceso de generación del código 'ref_payco', que se envía como parámetro en la URL. Antes, el código tenía este formato: 206715743, mientras que ahora es a65df208e9a272cbbd659347.
Al validar si esta referencia está asociada a una transacción y al enviar el código de la versión anterior, nunca se obtenía un resultado exitoso.
Se hizo la actualización del plugin y se realizó una transacción de prueba y el resultado fue positivo en la pagina de respuesta.
